# When I hover over the image, I want the overlay hover effect to activate

Tags: javascript, css, image, hover, overlay

When I hover over the image, I want the fade effect of the overlay to activate. I just started working at my first site and I am a javascript begginer, so I need some help. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spxkLucv/).

HTML Code:

```
<div class = "leftpart">    
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img src="images/test.jpg"/>
        <div class="flex-caption hvr-fade">Adventurer Lemon</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I do not have any javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Inset Css one more Class**

> Your Main Class add Hover Effect then use `.leftpart:hover` and then
>   your footer color change then after add `hvr-fade` then effece of main
>   Div hover

```
.leftpart:hover .hvr-fade
{
   background-color: #2098d1;
   color: white;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/u0ybe4d1/)

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it By css also

```
.leftpart a img:hover{opacity:0.8;}
```